# Public profile information

Tags: privacy, facebook-privacy

How do I stop Facebook naming my mother as a Parent in the "Born" section of my timeline that is viewable to the public?

I don't think I made this information public and I have even updated my profile details and deleted all family members, who apparently I could only see anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your mother mentioned you on her profile?

I would ask her if she could just make it more private, or delete it all together (but for some mothers this can be a tricky subject ;-) ).

Update: If that didn't help, and you are still related on Facebook. I would suggest contacting Facebook. Because Facebook has probably learned that information from you, and it isn't that easy to 'unlearn'. Try the 'Report a problem' button via the settings menu on the top right.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll tell her to make it viewable for friends only.

Comment: That would problably fix the problem

Comment: I've just talked her through it to change her setting in the family section to "Only Me" but nothings changed.  Maybe there's a bit of a delay in this being updated.  Will check tomorrow.

Comment: Have just checked it and it still has her as a parent.  Stupid!

Comment: Then I'm afraid it could be that Facebook has just learned that information from you, and you can't just delete it.. I've updated my answer for another suggestion.